# why a connection's signal have argument but slot doesn't have one?

Tags: c++, qt, signals, signals-slots, slots

Qt 4.8.1,The original code just like this:

```
connect(this->m_CodeMemoryComboBox, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(QString)),
      this, SLOT(updateCodeMemoryFormate()));
```

This really confuse me,[question]Can I pass an argument to the slot function when using QObject::connect?
That told me the argument should be match,but what happen here,the code will wrong if I remove that argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Qt documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html) describes this. Search for "(In fact a slot may have a shorter signature than the signal it receives because it can ignore extra arguments.)" under the heading "Signals and slots"

Basically, you can connect an `N`-parameter signal to an `M`-parameter slot if `M <= N` and the first `M` parameters match in type. Any leftover arguments from the signal are ignored by the slot.

Comment: @benhuan, if you have `signal(a, b, c, d)` and `slot(a, b)` the arguments `c` and `d` will be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

The [QT Doc](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html) says,

The signals and slots mechanism is type safe: The signature of a signal must match the signature of the receiving slot. (In fact a slot may have a shorter signature than the signal it receives because it can ignore extra arguments.)